# I have a bug when I recover a hashtag on twitter with eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0].text

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

I get an error when executing this code:

```
function TagEvent(eventMsg){
var Myname = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
var Hashtag = eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0].text;
var Isname = eventMsg.user.screen_name;
var Info = {
Quote: Myname,
Sender: Isname,
UseHashtag: Hashtag
};
console.log(Info);
if(Myname == 'NameOfMyBot' && Hashtag == 'Pic'){
  console.log("correct Hashtag");
T.post("statuses/update", {status:'@'+Isname+' reply test '}, tweeted);


}
```

and the error in the cmd is:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\picsbot\bot.js:31
var Hashtag = eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0].text;
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
at StreamingAPIConnection.TagEvent (C:\Users\Desktop\picsbot\bot.js:31:46)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at StreamingAPIConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
at module.exports.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\picsbot\node_modules\twit\lib\streaming-api-connection.js:314:56)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at module.exports.emit (events.js:188:7)
at module.exports.Parser.parse (C:\Users\Desktop\picsbot\node_modules\twit\lib\parser.js:47:16)
at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\picsbot\node_modules\twit\lib\streaming-api-connection.js:134:21)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Gunzip.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Gunzip.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at Gunzip.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:128:32)
at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:584:14)
```

But the tweet is still posted before the bot shutdown, and when I don't execute the function to post, I get no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var Hashtag = eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0].text;
```

to:

```
var Hashtag = eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0] && eventMsg.entities.hashtags[0].text;
```

Comment: So thanks it work but I have a little bug, he run a second time my code and the hashtag is undefined but he doesn't execute my function to post on twitter, so it's just very strange but it's still work.